# ggplot2: create a ploygon by connecting points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a polygon, with ggplot2, by connecting data points. However, it does not give me a polygon. What is the problem with my code?

```
 Longitude=c(0,30,30,0,0)
 Latitude=c(0,0,30,30,0)
 data.frame(lon=Longitude,lat=Latitude)%>%
       ggplot(aes(x=lon,y=lat))+geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: You want to replace `geom_line()` with `geom_path()`. That gives me a polygon on my machine.

Comment: Thanks! It solves my problem!

Comment: Pleasure to help you.